# Unable to display SQLite database in ListView (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, listview

I'm not able to display the database in ListView.
I would like to pass the 3 EditText information from DataInput.Java to Database.java in ListView.
Right now I'm able to save the detail form in DataInput.java and it will direct me to Database.java but the details are not shown in Database.java ListView.
I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

DataInput.java code (Details Form):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataInput extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText event, date, descrip;
    Button saveBtn;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_input);
        event = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.event_text);
        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date_text);
        descrip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descrip_text);
        saveBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title_ = event.getText().toString()+"\n";
                String date_ = date.getText().toString();
                String description_ = descrip.getText().toString();
                Helper dbHandler = new Helper(DataInput.this);
                dbHandler.insertUserDetails(title_, date_, description_);
                intent = new Intent(DataInput.this,Database.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Database.java code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Database extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);
        Helper db = new Helper(this);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = db.GetUsers();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Database.this,
                userList, R.layout.row, new String[]{"event","description","date"}, new int[]
                {R.id.event_text, R.id.date_text, R.id.descrip_text});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(Database.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Helper.java code:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "usersdb";
    private static final String TABLE_Users = "userdetails";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "event";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    public Helper(Context context){
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Users + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DESC + " TEXT"+ ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        // Drop older table if exist
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Users);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // **** CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations ***** //

    // Adding new User Details
    void insertUserDetails(String event, String date, String description){
        //Get the Data Repository in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
        cValues.put(KEY_EVENT, event);
        cValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        cValues.put(KEY_DESC, description);
        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_Users,null, cValues);
        db.close();
    }
    // Get User Details
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUsers(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT event, date, description FROM "+ TABLE_Users;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("event",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EVENT)));
            user.put("description",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESC)));
            user.put("date",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
            userList.add(user);
        }
        return  userList;
    }
    // Get User Details based on userid
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUserByUserId(int userid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT event, date, description FROM "+ TABLE_Users;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Users, new String[]{KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE, KEY_DESC}, KEY_ID+ "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(userid)},null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("event",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EVENT)));
            user.put("description",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESC)));
            user.put("date",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
            userList.add(user);
        }
        return  userList;
    }
    // Delete User Details
    public void DeleteUser(int userid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_Users, KEY_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(userid)});
        db.close();
    }
    // Update User Details
    public int UpdateUserDetails(String date, String description, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cVals = new ContentValues();
        cVals.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        cVals.put(KEY_DESC, description);
        int count = db.update(TABLE_Users, cVals, KEY_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        return  count;
    }
}
```

row.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```